# How can I disable the Compatibility Mode button in IE9?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode, x-ua-compatible

I cannot disable the IE Compatibility mode button in IE9.

My head and doctype look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if lte IE 8]> 
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-en" xml:lang="en-en" class="ie8">
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> 
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-en" xml:lang="en-en" class="ie9">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-en" xml:lang="en-en">
<!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="meta content here" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content here //-->
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I disable the compatibility mode button in IE9?

I thought I did my research. I applied every kind of fallback solution to display everything fine in every IE from 7 to 9 and up.

The client is complaining about the compatibility mode that when activated, it messes up the layout. Is there any way to disable that button?

Answer (score 18):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

> ***Chrome frame has been discontinued by Google as of Jan 2014 so the chrome=1 part is
>   not required***

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The "edge" forces standards mode (or latest rendering engine) in IE and the "chrome" is for Chrome Frame.

Further info available here:

- [Which X-UA-Compatible mode should I be using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692596/which-x-ua-compatible-mode-should-i-be-using)
- [Beyond DOCTYPE: Web Standards, Forward Compatibility, and IE8](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype)
- [20 Snippets You should be using from Html5 Boilerplate](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/snippets-html5-boilerplate/)

Comment: I finally got this to work (although I didn't include the `chrome` bit), when I moved this tag up to the *very first thing* after `<head>`

Comment: The location within `<head>` shouldn't matter. But the conditional tags such as `<!--[if gte IE 8]>` will interfere with the proper meta tag, so don't use them. The meta that causes the compatibility mode button to disappear (tested in IE10 on Windows 7) is `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Answer (score 5):

I was using conditional comments at the top of the page to embed an `ie` class based on version. (eg:)

```html
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

As a result, even though I was setting the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, the Compatability Mode button was still being shown in IE.

To fix, I had to move the conditional comments to the bottom of the page and use JS to apply the `ie` classes. The Compatibility button is no longer shown in IE when viewing my site.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9; IE=10; IE=EDGE; chrome=1">
  <head>
  <body>
     <!-- ..Other content... -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.flagAsIE = function(version) {
     var cls = document.body.parentElement.getAttribute('class');
     document.body.parentElement.setAttribute('class', "ie ie" + version + " " + cls);
   };
  </script>

  <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><script type='text/javascript'>flagAsIE('6');</script><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7 ]><script type='text/javascript'>flagAsIE('7');</script><![endif]-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonbox/archive/2011/03/27/removing-the-ie9-compatibility-button-and-html1115-warning.aspx

Change the order of your meta tags.

Comment: The problem persists. Even if I change it to:

`<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

Comment: Did you check for any similar messages in the console? That you're using conditional comments to declare the HTML tag raises flags for me.

Comment: I'm using a solution proposed by Paul Irish as a way to deal with x-browser compatibility. Only tags targetting particula browser get parsed. No messages popup in console.

Comment: The article you linked to in turn further links to a SVG with the workflow diagram for deciding which mode to use. Since it is 404, I've got it from Archive.org and [put the SVG here](http://pastebin.com/cgvVfFq9), the [resulting PNG image here](http://i.imgur.com/iqb3RsF.png).

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was the conditional comments that were causing the button to appear. Removing these and using feature detection instead to add my html classes has solved this problem. No amount of tinkering with the `X-UA-Compatible` stuff would remove the button.

I've used this set of [has.js](https://github.com/phiggins42/has.js/) detects:

```js
if (has("css-border-radius") && !has("input-attr-placeholder")) {
    html.className += ' ie9';
}

if (!has("css-border-radius") && !has("input-attr-placeholder")) {
    html.className += ' lt-ie9';
}

if (!has("css-box-sizing")) {
    html.className += ' ie7';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that somewhere in your js code you are using browser sniffing code like document.all, window.ActiveXObject, navigatror.userAgent, attachEvent, detachEvent etc.

Replace everything with feature detection code using 
[jquery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) and the button will disapear.