# Asp.net web page force document mode edge in IE?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that is not working properly in IE unless I hit F12 and change the document mode to "Edge" under emulation. Is this something I can do programmatically on the page so the user does not have to do this? TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which X-UA-Compatible mode should I be using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692596/which-x-ua-compatible-mode-should-i-be-using)

Comment: have you tried something like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`?

Comment: @bdimag If you're going to answer the question, do it as an answer. Not a comment.

Comment: @bdimag would this go at the top of my html code of the page? I get an error this is not supported outside script or asp region

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding the `X-UA-Compatible` META tag. This belongs in your `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

> Internet Explorer allows you to define which version's engine is used to render a page using the X-UA-Compatible META tag or HTTP header. A specific version can be designated or the latest version using the 'IE=edge' value.
>
> You can also add custom HTTP headers in the ASP.NET web.config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.webServer> 
      <httpProtocol> 
         <customHeaders> 
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" /> 
         </customHeaders> 
      </httpProtocol> 
   </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: would this go at the top of my html code of the page? I get an error this is not supported outside script or asp region

Comment: @user1342164 in the `<html><head>` section "as close to the top of the page's HEAD as possible" (e.g., above `title`)